# How can I improve this ETS model when residuals are correlated?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation

I am currently forecasting seasonally un-adjusted GDP and ran into an issue with residuals where there is a very large negative residual around the financial crises of 07/08.

I am using ETS models using the ets() function in R, and after trying every combination of Errors, trend, and seasonality 'ZZZ', I picked the model that resulted in the lowest AICc, which for this dataset was multiplicative errors, additive trend and multiplicative seasonality.

The errors have a mean = 0.0002, which is practically 0. However, the residuals are correlated (autocorrelation) with a Ljung-Box test p-value of 0.0003. The residual plot takes a dramatic downturn at around the start of the financial crisis. I therefore have three questions:

This means that I can improve the ETS model right?

In which case, what are some general steps that I can use to improve my ETS forecast?

Or does it mean that I should try other models such as ARIMA()()?

(This is for a pass fail assignment, I think I'll pass it based on everything else I've done, but here I have to stick with ETS).

Comment: This type of question, which is about methods rather than code, is better suited for Cross Validated.

Comment: nobody answered for 3 days there

Comment: Sorry, that's a drag.